# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'StoryFnReactReturnType' React Storybook in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm trying to get a simple Button component working with Storybook in typescript. I'm following [The Docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args) and [this example](https://dev.to/iamrishupatel/how-to-create-a-react-component-library-using-storybook-typescript-scss-and-rollup-4pin).

My Component and story is as follows:

components/Button.tsx:

```
import {FC} from 'react';

export interface ButtonProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    variant: "primary" | "danger";
    shape?: "rounded";
}

export const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({
    children,
    variant,
    shape,
    ...props
}) => {
    const classNames = `btn btn-${variant} btn-${shape}`;
    return (
        <button className={classNames} {...props}>
            {children}
        </button>
    );
};
```

stories/Button.stories.ts

```
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from '@storybook/react';

import { Button, ButtonProps } from '../components/Button';

export default {
    /*  The title prop is optional.
    * See https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview#configure-story-loading
    * to learn how to generate automatic titles
    */
    title: 'Button',
    component: Button,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Button>;

// We create a “template” of how args map to rendering
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Button> = (args) => <Button { ...args } />;

export const Primary = Template.bind({});

Primary.args = {
    primary: true,
    label: 'Button',
};
```

This line:

```
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Button> = (args) => <Button { ...args } />;
```

Throws the following error:

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'StoryFnReactReturnType'
```

[image: More Context]

Am I missing some sort of configuration?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First thing seems like you'll need to change the `Button.stories.ts` file to `.tsx`, regular typescript thinks the inside of the <> should be a type. After that, the `Primary.args` will need to match the ButtonProps you defined.

Comment: I was stumped for a few hours on this. "X" for "JSX". This solved my issue, thanks!